# Uniswap V2 Swap Fee

Tags: oracles, uniswap

On my calculation with formula X * Y = K and Swap Fee 0.3%, My Result Value of Input or Output Token Amount is nearly same as UniSwap V2 User Interface Estimated Amount.

But Sometimes, My result is different with Uniswap V2 UI Estimated Amount.

I am using thegraph GraphQL Uniswap V2 Subgraph for calculating.

Amount of two tokens from subgraph GraphQL request seems real-time. I checked with infrua.

so, It seems Uniswap V2 Subgraph is not problem though.

To get close value on Uniswap V2 UI, I must multiply ~0.8025 % swap fee.

Although Published Swap Fee is 0.3%..

Is there any other missing formula from my calculation?

I checked TWAP and Protocol Fee, but I can't find related UniSwap SDK or API endpoint for right calculation.

Below is my calculation for *x* ERC20 input and 1 ETH output with 0.3% fee situation

*((1 * amount Of X Of Pair) / (amount Of ETH Of Pair - 1)) * 1.003*